# user_tweets - What's going wrong with my Python code?

Tags: python, django, heroku, twitter

I'm using this code from a friend and when I run *heroku* it gives me this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ebooks.py", line 79, in <module>
    source_tweets_iter, max_id = grab_tweets(api,max_id)
  File "ebooks.py", line 51, in grab_tweets
    max_id = user_tweets[len(user_tweets)-1].id-1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know this error is telling about some empty list (which list? I don't know what it means) and the problematic line code belong to ebooks.py, that's it:

```
def grab_tweets(api, max_id=None):
    source_tweets=[]   
    user_tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(
        screen_name=user, count=200, max_id=max_id, include_rts=True, 
        trim_user=True, exclude_replies=True)   
    max_id = user_tweets[len(user_tweets)-1].id-1

    for tweet in user_tweets:
        tweet.text = filter_tweet(tweet)
        if len(tweet.text) != 0:    
            source_tweets.append(tweet.text)

return source_tweets, max_id
```

---

The original ebooks.py you can find here: https://gist.github.com/laurenorsini/f38c0113e41e9b4504a7

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: To format your code, indent each line of code by an additional 4 spaces. You can indent multiple lines of text by highlighting them all and pressing ctrl+k.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if there are no user tweets and if `user_tweets` was an empty list?

Then, doing `user_tweets[len(user_tweets) - 1]` would be equivalent to doing `user_tweets[0 - 1]` which is `user_tweets[-1]`. If you do `my_list[-1]`, you're telling Python to look for the last element in the list.

However, `user_tweets` is empty, then it's impossible to fetch the last element -- there's nothing in the list. So, Python throws an exception.

I would try and fix your code by adding a check to make sure that `user_tweets` isn't empty, and perhaps do something like this:

```
def grab_tweets(api, max_id=None):
    user_tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(
        screen_name=user, count=200, max_id=max_id, include_rts=True, 
        trim_user=True, exclude_replies=True)   

    if len(user_tweets) > 0:
        source_tweets=[]   
        max_id = user_tweets[len(user_tweets)-1].id-1

        for tweet in user_tweets:
            tweet.text = filter_tweet(tweet)
            if len(tweet.text) != 0:    
                source_tweets.append(tweet.text)

        return source_tweets, max_id
    else: 
        # return a default value?
        # throw an exception?
```

Comment: Now the code returns with this (if I change the to your code);;



Running `worker` attached to terminal... up, run.4420
  File "ebooks.py", line 67
    if __name__=="__main__":
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @PabloMurad -- are you mixing tabs and spaces? I left the 'else' block empty -- did you make sure to put something inside there?

Comment: In the `else` you should `return [],0` for this particular application otherwise you will get an error later in the code. This is the correct answer, however, and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting **user**?

To catch the error i'd do something like this:

```
def grab_tweets(api, max_id=None):
    source_tweets=[]   
    user_tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(
        screen_name=user, count=200, max_id=max_id, include_rts=True, 
        trim_user=True, exclude_replies=True)
    # if you're expecting it to succeed, use a try
    try:
        max_id = user_tweets[len(user_tweets)-1].id-1
    # if user_tweets is empty an IndexError is raised
    except IndexError:
        # do any internal logging here before the return
        return source_tweets, None

    for tweet in user_tweets:
        tweet.text = filter_tweet(tweet)
        if len(tweet.text) != 0:    
            source_tweets.append(tweet.text)

    return source_tweets, max_id
```

Or if you'd prefer to use an if:

```
def grab_tweets(api, max_id=None):
    source_tweets=[]
    max_id = None
    user_tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(
        screen_name=user, count=200, max_id=max_id, include_rts=True, 
        trim_user=True, exclude_replies=True)
    # you can use an if to prevent the error
    if len(user_tweets):
        max_id = user_tweets[len(user_tweets)-1].id-1

        for tweet in user_tweets:
            tweet.text = filter_tweet(tweet)
            if len(tweet.text) != 0:    
                source_tweets.append(tweet.text)

    return source_tweets, max_id
```

So that will catch your error, but you still need to test and make sure it works when you know it should return a populated list.  Check the user is set correctly, the API is working, etc.

Comment: I suppose user_tweets is about the twitter account, right? So take a look www.twitter.com/aphexpredator   there is no empty tweets, I dobn't know why it returns with this, but I will try!

Comment: But in your code snippet there's no reference to "user", so are you sure that it is set correctly and is not an empty or incorrect string?